# Which paging utility is being used?

Tags: bash

At a bash prompt, hitting tab twice will come up with a prompt such as `Display all 1770 possibilities? (y or n)`. What paging utility is bash using? It doesn't appear to be `less` or `more`. Is it something internal to bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is internal to bash, and controlled by the `page-completions` shell option.  I don't think you can configure it other than turning it on and off.  (Well, you can set `print-completions-horizontally`.)